# Как выполнить передачу нескольких данных из разных полей ввода формы между двумя различными страницами на чистом Js?

Tags: javascript

например у меня есть input я беру из него значение и хочу передать это значение в другой документ js  как это реализовать?
само задание было таким.

> Задание:
>
> Выполните передачу нескольких данных из разных полей ввода формы между
> двумя различными страницами.

как его реализовать на js  я не знаю.

Comment: Вариант через сервер. Отправляете данные на сервер. А вторая страница считывает их. Второй. Скидывает в localStorage а у второй странице просматривает его. 3 вариант это куки.

Comment: хых , это домашняя работа.  И мы еще не работаем с серверами. И преподаватель сказала передать значения из одного js документа в другой js. А я в  общем не знаю как.

Comment: Вариант 2 и 3 вам в помощь

Comment: если бы я знал что это, можете мне пожалуйста, скинуть информацию по этому. А то преподователь нам в общем ничего не сказала

Comment: https://code-boxx.com/pass-variables-between-pages-javascript/

Comment: не, ну ты рили троль

Comment: В чем дело? Примеров масса